# How to show labels in arcglobe for extruded features

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, 3d-analyst, arcglobe

I am trying to visualize lithology data in ArcGlobe, i.e, the representation of different types of soil data under the earth. This I have done properly by creating Z aware featureclass and extrusion properties. I have attached a picture, a representation in Globe. In this diagram each color in the 3D bars is one feature representing the type of soil.  Here I want to show the labels from the attribute table having the depth information of each feature. But when I am applying extrusion automatically, the Show Labels menu gets disabled. Is there any way to add labels programmatically (vertically next to each feature) like 3D text elements etc?

[image: screen shot of 3D representation]

Answer (score 2):

You need your labels to be Annotation

[image]

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Displaying_annotation_features_in_ArcGlobe/00q800000022000000/